# If I post spam, rude or abusive content on a site-specific meta, do I get the -100 reputation?

Tags: support, meta, spam, rude-or-abusive

Suppose this question was rude or abusive and it received 6 rude or abusive flags. Would I get the -100 reputation? Would it? Not that I *would* post rude or abusive here, but if I did...

Would 100 of my points be gone? In the trash? Flushed down the potty?

Comment: What are you planning to do if the answer is "no"?

Comment: @ArdentCoder Not post rude or abusive, I'm just curious.

Comment: Let's try it out. Everyone flag! /s

Comment: You'll get an IP ban + roundhouse kick by Jon Skeet!

Comment: @codygray I swear, there were a lot more comments than I see here. Where have they all gone?

Comment: I deleted obsolete comments that were discussing a tangential matter and had no relevance to the question being asked. Comments are routinely deleted when they become obsolete.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm really glad to see that you consider "Let's try it out. Everyone flag!" to be relevant.

Comment: @philipxy I tend to allow joke comments on Meta (in contrast to the main site). They help to blow off some steam. They only become a problem when there are so many joke comments that they are crowding out meaningful information, and/or when it becomes an extended conversation about the joke. At that point, I would delete them. But the comments I deleted here were all an extended conversation between me and one particular user about their own posts. That conversation was finished, and it has no general relevance, so there was no purpose served in keeping it around.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks--for your comment & moderation. That sounds just like what I expected & support.

Comment: @9694 Some good moderators allow the conversation to be completed and only then delete those comments as they divert from the topic of the post. However, [like I said here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348798/706547), sometimes useful points go down in this process. For example, the comment about revenge-downvoting which I initially posted here got deleted because it became conversational. It cannot be an answer as such, but makes a good comment: "If you post rude stuff in meta, you may get more than -100 because there are users who defeat the scripts and revenge-downvote you across sites"

Comment: That's the Meta effect. We can't really control the users who do that form of targeting. Maybe it's best not to be rude ever and wherever?

Comment: @E_net4likestoflag Of course, I'm not encouraging anyone to be rude. No matter how hard you try not to be rude, if your writing contains any sort of disagreement to the perspective of revenge-downvoters, then be ready for the treat haha (note: you can disagree with me, I'm not a revenge downvoter lol in fact, I downvote only in extreme cases).

Comment: @CodyGray Why did you close my post then immediately reopen it?

Comment: @9694 You already had four close votes, so I'm guessing it was just to get rid of them, rather than waiting for someone else to cast the fifth and *then* re-opening.

Comment: Please, could you refrain from making these frivolous edits? The question does not need a regular update with your reputation changes. Thanks.

Comment: @F1Krazy is correct. Moderators do that sometimes on Meta sites to invalidate pending close votes. It's the only way we have to do so. We cannot otherwise manually "cancel" pending close votes. Also agreed with yivi: please don't repeatedly make trivial updates to this post by just changing your reputation score. That doesn't affect the content of the post, and therefore doesn't need to bump it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No.

On site-metas there is no reputation for your meta-account (virtually [there is, long story](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234775/158100)) , so the -100 will have no (direct visible) impact.

Posting rude/abusive stuff that gets red-flagged and deleted might attract the attention of moderators. They might investigate and decide to take action. If they do you might lose a lot more than 100 rep, for example the right to participate for 6 to 8 weeks, also known as a [suspension](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18271/158100).

Do know that [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) (the uber-meta) is a "normal" site. If you go on a rampage on that site the -100 penalty will be applied to your user profile there.

If there isn't enough reputation you'll end-up at 1 because reputation never gets lower than that, no matter what you try.