# Why has my comment been deleted?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

I posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61013626/how-to-run-xcode-11-4-on-macos-mojave-10-14-6/61408149#61408149) to a question and a user asked a follow-up question in a comment:

> Why don't you do **X** instead?

This question seems to be interesting as it has a few upvotes. I'm pretty sure that I answered with another comment, something like

> Yes, that would be a valid alternative.

but my comment vanished. Why has my comment been deleted? Now the first comment is an unanswered follow-up question again. Can I see the reason for the deletion?

The unexplained deletion somewhat discourages me from reading/answering comments in the future, so I'd appreciate a clarification.

Comment: Comments are meant to ask for clarification and/or suggest improvements. They can be deleted at any time. If the comments contained some important information, why not incorporate it into the answer?

Comment: @BDL *Re: "If the comments contained some important information, why not incorporate it into the answer?"* I don't understand the underlying assumption in this argument: **comment == answer**!? I can also give you an example: [see this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398212/if-i-post-rude-or-abusive-on-a-site-specific-meta-do-i-get-the-100-reputation#comment774996_398212).

Comment: @Ardent What BDL is saying is, when someone asks you a clarification or follow-up question about your answer, it's usually a good idea to edit your response to that question into your answer. If one reader had that question, then it's likely that others will, too, and your edit will improve the overall quality of your answer. Plus, even if the comment(s) are deleted, nothing will be lost. The whole idea on this site is that comments are temporary and transient: all important information that needs to stick around should go into answers.

Comment: @CodyGray I agree with that. The problem is that sometimes "The whole idea on this site is that comments are temporary" is misused to delete comments before the information is incorporated into the answer, before the addressee responds, and many other reasons which I have already said elsewhere (most of which got censored for unknown reasons). Or, sometimes unknowingly misused because if there were an option to edit the undesirable part of the comment, then it could exist until the useful information is saved in some answer like you people want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your comment was deleted by a moderator, but not in response to a flag. (I guess the moderator must have come across the comment while reading the post for some other reason and decided to delete it? I'm not sure. *None* of the posts on that Q&A have ever been flagged, so I'm not sure what would have brought the Q&A to the attention of a moderator.)

At any rate, I very much disagree with the moderator's decision to delete that comment. It was not obsolete, since it was replying to another user's clarification question and it provided useful information to future readers.

I've undeleted the comment now.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the undeletion. In case I, or someone else, has the same question again in the future about a deleted comment, what's the preferred way to contact the moderators? If I understand it correctly, there was no way for me to see the reason for the deletion or dispute the deletion directly.

Comment: @Theo That's correct; there is no information available to regular users about deleted comments. This is only available to moderators. Meta is the best place to ask about it and/or request undeletion, just as you've done here. It should be extremely rare that deleted comments should ever have to be *discussed*, much less undeleted. This seems like a curious, one-off mistake.

Comment: Perhaps there was no decision and it was a simple misclick. It happens, even sentient robots make a mistake from time to time.

Comment: My comment has again vanished. What's going on?